# X wants to know when we'll receive Y

Tags: grammar

I am trying to translate the following sentence.

> Tom wants to know when will receive the package

My attempt is

> 톰님이 언제 특히를 받다고 알고 싶어요

My thought on why this might be correct is because what Tom wants to know is quoted so I used the -다고 pattern. On the word for package I am not too sure, I just used Naver Dictionary for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard verb form for embedding a question in another sentence as in your example is -지.  The quote form -다고/라고 is used when relaying a regular statement, and -냐고 can be used when the verb is an explicit questioning or demanding kind like 묻다 (ask/question), 질문하다 (ask), 추궁하다 (question/interrogate by pressuring).

So,

- 톰 님이 언제 택배를 받는지 (or 받을지) 알고 싶어요.
  ("package" may be 소포 (traditional term used by the post office) or 택배 (any home delivery.)
- 톰 님이 언제 택배를 받는지 / 받느냐고 / 받을 거냐고 물어 봤어요.  (with 묻다, you can say either -지 or -냐고)
- 톰 님이 벌써 택배를 받았다고 말했어요 = Tom said he had already received the package (relaying a statement with -다고).